# Unity2D Melee Combat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming and C#. I'm trying to build a melee system for my platform game following tutorials on yt.

This is my PlayerAttack script:

```
using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour {
    //[SerializeField] private float attackCooldown;
    [SerializeField] private float range;
    [SerializeField] private int damage;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask enemyLayer;


    public Transform AttackPoint;

    //private float cooldownTimer = Mathf.Infinity;

    private Animator anim;
    private Enemy enemyHealth;




    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        enemyHealth = GetComponent<Enemy>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Attack");
            Attack();
            Debug.Log("attacking");
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (AttackPoint == null)
            return;

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(AttackPoint.position, range);

    }



    void Attack()
    {


        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, range, enemyLayer);

        foreach (Collider2D Enemy in hitEnemies)
        {

            Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);   

        }



    }

}
```

and this one is the EnemyHealth script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int startingHealth;

    public int currentHealth;
    public Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int _damage)
    {
        currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth - _damage, 0, startingHealth);

        if (currentHealth > 0)
        {
            //hurt animation
            //invulnerability
        }

        else
        {
            //die animation
            GetComponentInParent<EnemyPatrol>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<EnemyMelee>().enabled = false;
        }


    }

    void Die()
    {
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {

            Debug.Log("Enemy Dead!");
            Destroy(gameObject);
            //die animation
        }


    }
}
```

I'm getting an error from the Unity editor "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line 61 of the PlayerAttack:
enter code here

Enemy.transform.GetComponent().TakeDamage(damage);

I checked the scripts names and they are fine, and I checked also if I missed something in the editor , I don't know what's wrong.

When I hit the enemy the game crashes and i get this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);` on everything that has collider but some of those objects don't have the `Enemy` component so you can't call `TakeDamage` on them. That is where the error comes from. To fix it you have to find only the enemy game objects. To do this you can [assign tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) to your enemy and check the ones with `Enemy` tag through the script like this:

```
  foreach (Collider2D Enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
          if (Enemy.tag == "Enemy")
            Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);               
        }
```

There is another way to do it without tags which I don't recommend:

```
  foreach (Collider2D Enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
          if (Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>() != null)
            Enemy.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);             
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the player has hit the enemy or not:

```cs
foreach (Collider2D hitEnemy in hitEnemies) {
    if(hitEnemy.TryGetComponent(out Enemy enemy)) {
        enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

**Other than the answer:**
In your PlayerAttack.cs script, you have a field `enemyHealth` which you are trying to get a reference to it using `enemyHealth = GetComponent<Enemy>();` in your `Awake()` method. This doesn't get a reference to it because of Enemy.cs and PlayerAttack.cs scripts are attached to different gameobjects.